# SpriteNode disappears when returning to GameScene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have a background sprite that I display in my GameScene. When I go to another scene (BuildViewController) and come back by background is gone. I'm sure it is a simple fix and it isn't anymore complicated than what I have said above. Heres some code :)

```
while length <= 6 {
    while wide <= 6 {
        let imageViewBackground = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:0 + (wide*100), y:0 + (length*200), width: 100, height: 200))
        imageViewBackground.image = UIImage(named: "grass.png")
        self.view?.addSubview(imageViewBackground)
        self.view?.sendSubview(toBack: imageViewBackground)
        wide = wide + 1
    }
    wide = 0
    length = length + 1
}
```

Comment: why are you using UIImage and UIImageViews in your GameScene?

Comment: You need more information. like where this code gets called from, how it gets called, when it gets called etc.

Comment: That background is not a Sprite but a UIImageView. None of the code you have posted is SpriteKit. Are you sure you are using SpriteKit?

Answer (score 0):

You may be finding that by adding your imageView to the view controller along with the SKScene that things are drawing all oddly (it could also be that your imageView is getting dealloc'd but I can't say based on your code).

I'm assuming you're using the basic Xcode template to set up your views and stuff; so to make the grass, try something like this in your `GameScene` class instead of the code above (which I assume is in your `GameViewController` class). You can put the code in `didMove(to view: SKView)` or you can add a `sceneDidLoad()` func. Make a [SKSpriteNode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skspritenode) for the grass and tile it like you are doing already. The two methods I mention here are the ones most closely related to the `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` methods in UIViewController land.

```
while length <= 6 {
    while wide <= 6 {
        let grassSprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "grass.png")
        grassSprite.position = CGPoint(x: (wide * 100), y: (length * 200))
        self.addChild(grassSprite
        wide += 1
    }
    wide = 0
    length += 1
}
```

All of this being said, it appears you are trying to make a grass background for something, in which case, you should probably look into `SKTileGroup` which has some nice conveniences.

Comment: it's SKSpriteNode ;)

Comment: Thanks @RonMyschuk for saving me from the "I pasted your code into my project but it doesn't compile" comments.